# Haskell - sum a list of lists using foldr/foldl

Tags: list, haskell

I'm trying to write functions to sum a list of lists (type `Integer`). I have already done it using `map`:

```
summat :: [[Integer]] -> Integer
summat (x:xs) = sum . map sum $ (x:xs)
```

but can't figure out, how to get it work using `foldr`/`foldl`. I tried something like:

```
summat2 :: [[Integer]] -> Integer
summat2 xs = foldr suma 0 xs
        where suma x _ = ???
```

but of course it only produces many errors. Do you have any hint for me? Maybe something with `concat`?

Comment: You could certainly use `concat` before performing the sum using a fold, and honestly that's how I'd do it.  `concat` is a lazy function, so you'd get good performance from it still with minimal effort

Comment: well, start with what is the type of that `x`? Then you will know how to use `foldr`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to avoid any other functions that act on multiple elements of collections, try this

```
foldr ((+) . foldr (+) 0) 0
```

This just uses (+), foldr, and (.).

Comment: I think `foldl'` would be preferred over `foldr` here.

Comment: Ok I wrote it using `foldl` :  

`summat3 :: [[Integer]] -> Integer`    
`summat3 (x:xs) = foldl (+) 0 (map sum (x:xs))`  how to get it in form jamshidh used?

Comment: Just add a flip- `foldl (flip $ (+) . foldl (+) 0) 0`